# Get key based on JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to know the recursive keys in a JSON Object. For example, the JSON Object is like

```
{
    "Division1" : {
        "checked": true,
        "level": 1,
        "District1-1": {
            "checked": true,
            "level": 2,
            "Area1-1-1": {
                "checked": true,
                "level": 3,
                "Project1-1-1-1": {
                    "checked": true,
                    "level": 4
                }
            },
            "Area1-1-2": {
                "checked": true,
                "level": 3,
                "Project1-1-2-1": {
                    "checked": true,
                    "level": 4,
                    "05": {
                        "checked": true,
                        "level": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am able to find **"Project1-1-1-1"**, I should be able to find and store **"Area1-1-1", "District1-1", "Division1"** in an array, how to perform a recursive search to store the parent/grandparent keys?

I am using javascript to make this possible

Current JS:

```
        var parent = [];
        $.test.getObjects = function(obj, key, val) {
            var objects = [];
            for (var i in obj) {

                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){  continue; }
                if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                   // console.log(i);
                    parent.push(i);
                    objects = objects.concat($.test.getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
                }
                //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
                if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
                    objects.push({"parent": parent,"children": obj});
                } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
                    //only add if the object is not already in the array
                    if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                        objects.push({"parent": parent,"children": obj});
                    }
                }
            }
            return objects;
        };
```

Comment: Could you add the code you have to find **Project1-1-1-1**?

Comment: What is the question? What does it mean to "store parent/grandparent keys" ?

Comment: @IvanKuckir I just mentioned colloquially to refer the **Area1-1-1**, **District1-1**, **Division1**

Answer (score 0):

I'm reworking my previous answer, so I'm deleting it. Looks like I didn't understand your question at all :)

AFAIK, Javascript arrays/dictionaries don't store parent relationships, so the only way I think you could do so is to check the whole tree starting from the parent. The steps you should follow recursively:

1- Obtain the array of children (using the Object.keys(var) method)

2- If it's not the key you're looking for, run the recursive method for each child. As a parameter, you should pass an array, accumulating all the previous keys obtained in previous runs, and add the key of the children you're just about to visit.

3- If it's the key you're looking for, just store the so-called array you've been accumulating and there you are!

Following this, you should be able to do a simple recursive method with a couple of parameters: the current point of the array you're checking, and the so-called accumulative array that will potentially become the result.

I don't know if there's a more simple approach than this.